# script to sort sheet by 2 colums

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Please help make the script. As written below, I wrote a script that worked for some time. Now it does not work and I need help writing a new one.
The challenge is this: when you make changes in column F, K and O - occurs first check the availability of the text in the column to the - then if there is a text should start sorting first by F column - then sorting by a column O
There is a scheme of action sequences by the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qSx6LqB8U-d01URS1BcEVtNGs/view?usp=sharing

I will be happy if someone can help me.
In any case, thanks for your time and attention :) Have a nice day :)

29/03/17 I need help "Service error: spreadsheets"
A very recently worked script:

```
    function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var cols = r.getColumn();
var rows = r.getRow();
var who = ss.getRange(rows,11).getValue();
if (who !== "") {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
sheet.sort(6);
sheet.sort(15);}
}
```

Today received an error:
Service error: spreadsheets

The script stopped working at all, help, please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following how this completes your action sequence flow chart, but I believe this should get it running as before. I've seen other posts where people get this same Service Error message form previously working scripts, and I believe Google is trying to change how certain tasks are done to help their server loads.

```js
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var cols = r.getColumn();
var rows = r.getRow();
var who = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(rows,11).getValue();
if (who !== "") {
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.sort(6);
sheet.sort(15);}
}
```

I removed the duplicate definition of var ss and tweaked var ss, var who and var sheet to work without it.